# How to export a variable \ array \ function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, fetch

Fetching an array of `users` with jsonplaseholder. This array must be exported to another file and there already get what you need from the array (the `name` property of each of the `users`). I encounter the fact that the `.map ()` method is not a function

**get data:**

```
const fetch = require("node-fetch");

let getMain = new Promise(async function (resolve, reject) {
    let response = await fetch('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users');
    resolve(response.json());
    reject();
});

getMain.then(mainData => {
    let dataLength = mainData.map(item => item.name.length);
    //console.log(dataLength, mainData);
    return Promise.resolve(dataLength)
})

    .catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err)
    });
//console.log(getMain);
function optionForPie(array) {
    return  array.map(item => item.name.length);
}

export let dataLength = optionForPie(getMain);
    console.log(dataLength);
```

**error:**

```
export let dataLength = optionForPie(getMain);
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'
?[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:895:18)?[39m
?[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:995:10)?[39m
?[90m    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:32)?[39m
?[90m    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:727:14)?[39m
?[90m    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1047:10)?[39m
?[90m    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11?[39m
```

Comment: [Never pass an `async function` as the executor to `new Promise`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43036229/1048572)!

Comment: Apart from the issue that you're not using ES6 modules when loading the module, `getMain` is a promise not an array that you can `.map()` over. You *cannot* export an array, it won't be loaded yet.

Comment: Can i do export inside `getMain().then()` ?

Comment: No. The best thing you can do is to export a promise.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use ES6 Module syntax, you have to install babel npm package to transpile your ES6 to a commonjs target.

If you don't install babel, you have to use `module.exports`.